# How do I stop my monitor from blacking out in Vista

Tags: windows-vista, display, graphics-card

I've started having problems with one of my two monitors in Vista.  It starts flickering and then blacks out.  If I change the resolution, the monitor starts working again, and then is fine if I change it back to native resolution.  It will then work fine until the next session (after a reboot or the energy saver screen save has taken effect).  It used to only do this after reboots or once or twice a month.  Has anyone experienced anything similar to this?  Is it a driver issue or might it some how be video card or Monitor related?  Any help would be appreciated as it is starting to get really annoying.

Edit: Monitors are Samsung Synchmaster 245BW's.  The graphics card is an Nvidia GeForce 8800 GTS (driver version 181.22)

Comment: Specify your monitor and graphic card, please.

Comment: Are these episodes followed by a notification area balloon who mentions something about the adapter has stopped responding and has been restarted?

Comment: No, there is no notification baloon.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Must be a Vista bug, it appears the solution to my problem was to upgrade to Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

Does wiggling the cable cause the screen to drop out in the same fashion?

If it does, I suspect you either have a loose connection, or a dry joint.

Failing that, upgrade your drivers from your manufacturer to the latest version (and don't use the ones on the manufacturer's CD, they are almost always fail :P)

Answer (score 1):

I find that when this happens, if I turn my monitor on and off once, it normally works perfectly.

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't work.  The only way I have found to fix it is switching resolutions.

Comment: wow ... this is really different that SF or SO. Normally there are right answers, but with this stuff, hardware is so different you can't really downvote people because it might work for them.

Answer (score 0):

Is the monitor going into sleep mode after the flickering? Sometimes clicking on the monitor's settings buttons can wake them back up..

Could be a power issue. Maybe try powering that monitor off a different plug to the rest of your system.

You could try and swap monitors around, that will tell you if its the monitor, or the feed from the video card that's causing the problem. (ie, swap your left and right monitors around)